# Entity Framework RPC vs batch performance

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, iis, application-pool

I have an .net application with application pool (IIS) on one machine and SQL server on another machine. Application uses entity framework to work with DB. I have two options to solve my task (getting data from db). At example i have List of Entity1 in application and i need to get List of Entity2 from DB (Entity2 is connected to Entity1 by Foreign Key).
I have 2 options to do it.

First one is to make one batch request to DB:

```
public List<Entity2> GetEntities(List<long> entity1IDs)
{
    db.Entity2.Where(e2 => entity1IDs.Contains(e2.Entity1ID)).ToList();
}
...
var entities2 = GetEntities(entities1.Select(e => e.Entity1ID).ToList());
foreach (var entity2 in entities2)
{
    ...
}
```

Second one is to make n rpc requests to DB:

```
foreach (var entity1 in entities1)
{
    var entity2 = entity1.entity2;
    ...
}
```

I am pretty sure that first option must have better performance, because there is only one request to DB. But how does it affect application pool? Yes it's only one request but it's a lot of dynamic data in memory in one unit of time. And if we have millions of records in DB then we have one big request to DB with high memory usage in app pool and cpu usage to operate with big amount of data (option 1) vs millions of requests to DB with low memory usage in app pool and cpu usage.

Anyway I am inclined to the first option, but want to know more arguments and maybe some practice results and analysis.

Also is there any analysis tool to track how much CPU usage is going for application pool to work with SQL and how much is going to operate with data in application pool to make a comparsion?

Comment: Keywords being "benchmarking" and "profiling", which _you_ will have to do. There is no silver bullet solution for this problem, it depends on too many variables.

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, that's why I asked about analysis tools for application pool to make practice tests and get best solution for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing depends on your server resources and what you find more expensive. Usually memory is cheap, but network is more expensive, and performance is more of an issue.

What you are doing is trying to optimize your solution before you actually faced a relevant problem. I would go with the first one, since usually network is more of an issue, and creating a connection every time can hurt performance. If you actually run into problems because of your big query - which is very unlikely in most systems - then you should look into improving your code to fit your specific needs.